# Ruby Array Having Hash Pairs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the ruby array as following :

```
array = [{"id"=>8, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>5, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>7, "book_id"=>10743}, {"id"=>9, "book_id"=>10743}]
```

I want a new array combining the result of `ids` having same `book_id`.

**Expected Result**:

```
array = [{"book_id"=>14238, "id"=>[8,5]}, {"book_id"=>10743, "id"=>[7,9]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that this is easy to understand, but it is concise:

```
array.group_by {|item| item["book_id"] }.map do |k, v|
  { "book_id" => k, "id" => v.map {|item| item["id"] } }
end

=> [{"book_id"=>14238, "id"=>[8, 5]}, {"book_id"=>10743, "id"=>[7, 9]}]
```

---

The first transformation done by `group_by` rearranges your array so that items with the same `book_id` are grouped together:

```
array.group_by {|item| item["book_id"] }
 => {14238=>[{"id"=>8, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>5, "book_id"=>14238}], 10743=>[{"id"=>7, "book_id"=>10743}, {"id"=>9, "book_id"=>10743}]}
```

The second transformation (`map`) reformats the hash produced by the group_by into a list of hashes, and the second `map` collects the id's into a list.

Comment: I copied my solution from irb, to paste here and I saw my answer was exactly as yours +1

Comment: my answer was very close to yours same as `the Tin Man` I have deleted bcz it was not satisfied expected output. 1+

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block to resolve the values of keys that are contained in both of the hashes being merged.

**Code**

```
def aggregate(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    f = { g["book_id"]=>{ "id"=>[g["id"]], "book_id"=>g["book_id"] } }
    h.update(f) do |_,ov,nv|
      ov["id"] << nv["id"].first
      ov
    end
  end.values
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [{"id"=>8, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>5, "book_id"=>14238},
       {"id"=>7, "book_id"=>10743}, {"id"=>9, "book_id"=>10743},
       {"id"=>6, "book_id"=>10511}]

aggregate(arr)
  #=> [{"id"=>[8, 5], "book_id"=>14238},
  #    {"id"=>[7, 9], "book_id"=>10743},
  #    {"id"=>[6],    "book_id"=>10511}]
```

**Alternative output**

Depending on your requirements, you might consider building a single hash instead of another array of hashes:

```
def aggregate(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
    h.update({ g["book_id"]=>[g["id"]] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } }
end

aggregate(arr)
  #=> {14238=>[8, 5], 10743=>[7, 9], 10511=>[6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hash for the output for easier lookups and/or reuse:

```
array = [{"id"=>8, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>5, "book_id"=>14238}, {"id"=>7, "book_id"=>10743}, {"id"=>9, "book_id"=>10743}]

hash = array.group_by{ |h| h['book_id'] }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.flat_map{ |h| h['id'] }]}.to_h
# => {14238=>[8, 5], 10743=>[7, 9]}
```

The keys are the `book_id` values, and the associated array contains the `id` values.

---

The expected result of

```
array = [{"book_id"=>14238, "id"=>[8,5]}, {"book_id"=>10743, "id"=>[7,9]}]
```

isn't a good structure if you're going to do any sort of lookups in it. Imagine having hundreds or thousands of elements and needing to find `"book_id" == 10743` in the array, especially if it's not a sorted list; The array would have to be walked until the desired entry was found. That is a slow process.

Instead, simplify the structure to a simple hash, allowing you to easily locate a value using a simple Hash lookup:

```
hash[10743]
```

The lookup will never slow down.

If the resulting data is to be iterated in order by sorting, use

```
sorted_keys = hash.keys.sort
```

and

```
hash.values_at(*sorted_keys)
```

to extract the values in the sorted order. Or iterate over the hash if the key/values need to be extracted, perhaps for insertion into a database.

Comment: This is not the expected output

Comment: That's correct. Sometimes the expected output is not the best way to work with data. Stack Overflow isn't just about returning the expected output, it's also about educating that there are simpler ways of doing things that accomplish the same results. Consider how easily the expected output could be searched or reused, vs. a simple hash. The expected output has to be iterated just to find a particular book_id, which would grow slower and slower as the initial array grows. That's hardly efficient.